# Don’t include the edits I’ve suggested in the review count

Tags: feature-request, documentation, review-queues

I noticed that if you suggest a change to a Documentation example, in the review section the number of pending edits will include yours, however you will be unable to review your own change. Should this be changed so that your suggestion is not counted? I am **NOT** requesting to be able to approve my own edits, but should your edits be counted when showing the number of pending changes to be reviewed, if you cannot access them?

Comment: `should your edits be counted when showing the number of pending changes`  Well, just as you said, it's showing the number of pending changes.   It's not showing the number of reviews you're able to review.

Comment: @Servy Yes, but when reviewing, unless you cannot access a category at all, you can review anything is there. Your own edits are an exception which might confuse someone who just got access to the review feature.